# What does "t" refer to in this SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a simple query in my code (shown below) written by my colleague. What does `t` mean here? Also what is the role of the `;` inside the query? I am dead sure that `t` is not any table, nor any field anywhere in my database. And guess what this query works!!

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT AttemptNo FROM attempt_exercise 
                 WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode)t;
                ";
```

The code follows like this (for any other info if required):

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uId", uId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eId", eId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", mode);
attemptCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
_conn.Close();
return attemptCount;
```

Comment: @BenLee No, when I remove the t, I get the error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague created a query (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) with a subquery that he named `t`. This `t` is just a temporary table name which refers to

> ```
> SELECT AttemptNo FROM attempt_exercise 
>   WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode
> ```

He could have feasibly named it `temp` to be a bit more explicit. The reason that this becomes like a table is because, in MySQL, a `SELECT` query returns rows of data which act like a table. So, this inner query gets the `AttemptNo`, and creates a temporary table `t`. The outer query then counts this data.

The `;` inside the query is to make it a full statement when the *string* query is called by the program. If this weren't included, the String `query` wouldn't contain a valid MySQL statement. The final `;` is to complete the assignment for the variable.

Comment: How is the query `SELECT AttemptNo FROM attempt_exercise 
  WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode` a table first of all? It returns a value, not a table name isn't it?

Comment: @nawfal it returns rows of tables which make up a "table" of data. Then, `t` names this as an alias

Comment: Oh, I wished if you added that info to your answer so that it becomes clear and perfect :)

Comment: The `;` inside the query is not always needed. It is surely needed if you have 2 or more queries/statements. It's the separator (delimiter), so the SQL parser knows where one statement finishes and where the next starts.

Comment: @ypercube I disagree, the final `;` is part of the String definition for `query`, isn't it? It's not part of the SQL statement itself.

Comment: @simchona: Right, I was referring to the inside `;`, edited my comment.

Comment: @ypercube Depending on how the queries were run, would you think it'd be safer to have the inner `;`? I'm not claiming to be an expert, but MySQL always yelled at me if I didn't end statements with a semicolon

Comment: It depends on how you run your queries. Different interfaces have different behaviours. Some require a semicolon. Some do not and even disbehave if you do add one (those usually cannot run more than one statement per call)

Comment: But your answer is fine. Those interfaces that do not require a semicolon, probably understand when you have just one statement and it (the ;) themselves.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, that semicolon is unnecessary :)

Comment: @nawfal: Since you tested that, we know. What is the language and inteface you are using? C#, C++, PHP, other?

Comment: @ypercube  C# [1 more to go] :)

Comment: @simchona - It's more like an "inline view" than it is a "table".

Answer (score 3):

`t` is an alias for your subquery, and you need it.

So you could have written:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attempt_exercise 
WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode;
```

and that would have been equivalent.

But were you to try to join your subquery to something else, you would have likely seen the need a bit sooner:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
   (SELECT AttemptNo FROM attempt_exercise 
    WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode) t
JOIN AttemptStatisticsTableOfSomeSort a
    ON t.AttemptNo = a.AttemptNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just an alias for the nested query. The semi colon inside the query is a statement terminator - its part of the ANSI sql standard.

Answer (score 1):

An alias to the subquery. If subquery appears as tablesource in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses - it should have an alias.

Answer (score 1):

All temporary tables created in this manner (ie. in the `FROM` clause) MUST have an alias they can be referred to by. In this case, the alias is `t`. If the coder were more clear in their writing, they wouldn't have omitted the optional `AS` before it.

The point is, it's just a temporary name and not really important in this scenario, but it required to make it work.

That said, the following is probably more efficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AttemptNo) FROM attempt_exercise WHERE FK_UId = @uId AND FK_EId = @eId AND Mode = @mode
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks. I appreciate your effort to give a more efficient query, but no in my case I need not just distinct, but all the `AttemptNo` :) Nevertheless tweak-able, thanks :)

Comment: @kolink: The OP's query does not count distinct `Attemptno`. It counts all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The semi colon is a line delimiter for MySql commands. Have a look under the first bullet point on here for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html